# Android and ActionBarCompat: how to change visibility of actions at runtime on pre-ICS devices?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an `Activity` that `extends ActionBarActivity` taken from the `ActionBarCompat` code sample and I'm trying to show/hide menu items (actions) at runtime.

I've tried using `setVisible()` on the `MenuItem` and works for ICS, but in pre-ICS it only change visibility of menu items (menu button press) whereas the `ActionBar` doesn't get notified of menu changes.

Any solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but have you looked at ActionBarSherlock (http://abs.io)? You can definitely change the visibility of menu items on pre-ICS devices. Even if you don't want to switch your `ActionBar` implementation, you may be able to find the solution in the ActionBarSherlock source.

Comment: That's a good idea. Any pointers to where one should look?

Answer (score 5):

I created multiple alternatives of the action bar items under /res/menu/. I keep a member to indicate which one I am using right now. to replace the menu, I call:

```
protected void setMenuResource(int newMenuResourceId)
{
    _menuResource = newMenuResourceId;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

And I override onCreateOptionsMenu() to:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    if (_menuResource != 0)
    {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(_menuResource, menu);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Now, if I want to change the action Items, I call:

```
setMenuResource(R.menu.actionbar_menu_X);
```

Comment: Note that `invalidateOptionsMenu()` is API 11 and above only.

Comment: It it implemented by the Sherlock library for API 10; it is also implemented as getActionBarHelper().invalidateOptionsMenu() in the compatibility library.

Comment: It is not implemented int the ActionBarHelper class. Can you explain it in more detail.

Comment: @Steelight What do you mean by "getActionBarHelper()"?  There is no such api method that I could find.

Answer (score 4):

This is how i solved it:

In ActionBarHelperBase.java of actionbarcompat project

...

```
private View addActionItemCompatFromMenuItem(final MenuItem item) {

final int itemId = item.getItemId();
```

....

The creator of this class copy properties of object, but didn't copy the id of item, so it is impossible to find it later with fiven id.

So i added it in that method:

```
...
actionButton.setId(itemId);
...
```

and in the same class i just use:

```
@Override
public void hideMenuItemById(int id, boolean show){
    getActionBarCompat().findViewById(id).setVisibility(show? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
}
```

Hope it helps You.

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer and add a bit more detail. I tried this but could not get it to work. Are there other steps involved?

Comment: The method cannot be called from the activity. One can only call methods from ActonBarHelper. I cant figure out how this code should work.

Comment: Please see the demo project for implementation https://github.com/AlienAsRoger/CourtDeadlines

Answer (score 3):

You have to call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() which is the relevant method for an ActionBarActivity:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()